# What kind of graph would $|x-h| + |y-k| = 1$ give?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

I know that $(x - h)^2 + (y - k)^2 = 1$ is a circle, but what would the graph look like for     $|x-h| + |y-k| = 1$ and why would it look like that?

Comment: "hint": http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7Cx-5%7C+%2B+%7Cy-4%7C+%3D+1

Comment: "Related": http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144211/relationship-between-two-absolute-value-curves

Comment: The equation $|x|+|y|=1$ can be split into four cases and then translated.

Comment: Since you make the comparison to a (Euclidean) circle, I'll point out that $|x-h| + |y-k| = 1$ is the corresponding taxicab circle.  See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry

Answer (score 5):

It will have a graph very similar to the graph of $|x|+|y|=1$, except displaced so as to have "centre" $(h,k)$. Now you need to graph $|x|+|y|=1$. First deal with the first quadrant part. That's just $x+y=1$. Now deal with the second quadrant part. In the second quadrant, $|x|=-x$, and $|y|=y$, so we are looking at $-x+y=1$. Continue.